# Unit Test POST with @WebMvcTest - @MockBean Service returns null

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking

I'm trying to unit test a controller to save a `Brand` entity. In this test, I'm creating a `Brand` that I expect to get back and then I'm posting JSON to the controller. Originally, I was relying on `pass-by-reference` so my controller method was basically doing:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> save(@Valid @RequestBody Brand brand, BindingResult bindingResult) {

  validate(brand, null, bindingResult);
  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      throw new InvalidRequestException("Invalid Brand", bindingResult);
  }

  this.brandService.save(brand); // pass by reference
  MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = jsonView(JSON_VIEWS.SUMMARY.value, brand);
  return new ResponseEntity<>(mappingJacksonValue, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Note that I wasn't actually using the returned `Brand` from the service. When I tested this way, my test was failing because the controller was returning the JSON I passed in, and since the service is mocked, the controller didn't return the brand I was expecting, which was to have an ID. So I changed the controller to do this:

```
brand = this.brandService.save(brand);
```

However, when I debug, the brand returned from the mocked service is null. Below is my test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BrandController.class)
public class BrandSimpleControllerTest {

  @Autowire
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private BrandService brandService;

  @Test
  public void testSave() throws Exception {
    Brand brand = new Brand();
    brand.setId(1L);
    brand.setName("Test Brand");

    when(this.brandService.save(brand)).thenReturn(brand);

    this.mockMvc.perform(this.post("/api/brands")
      .content("{\"name\": \"Test Brand\"}"))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is("Test Brand")));
  }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, problem solved. The issue was that the object you mock in the service call has to be identical to the object passed into the controller so when the mock looks at what is expected, it says "oh, you gave me this and so you want that". Here's the modified code that makes it work:

```
Brand brand = new Brand();
brand.setId(1L);
brand.setName("Test Brand");
brand.setDateCreated(new LocalDateTime());
brand.setLastUpdated(new LocalDateTime());

// since all I'm passing into the controller is a brand name...
when(this.brandService.save(new Brand("Test Brand"))).thenReturn(brand);
```

Comment: I almost pulled out my hairs last night because of that issue. I used Mockito.any(). But I know at some point I will have to send an exact object in request. Then only I can expect an exact object in response so I can do assertion. I will save this answer for such situations.

Comment: Hello @Gregg, do you mind elaborating more on what do you mean by "identical" ? I have 2 "identical" objects(DTO) being passed in a service method call(1 in my @Test and 1 in my controller) and they have the same exact property values, but my controller test(`@WebMvcTest`) where i am mocking a service call(`MockBean`) is not working. Basically, i am mocking `service.method(someObjectDTO)`, and in my  @Test, i am returning true for this method like so: `given(service.method(someObjectDTO)).willReturn(true);`, but when the test is running, the same method in the controller is returning false :-(

Comment: Hello @Gregg, I solved my issue by using, `given(service.method((someObjectDTO) any(Object.class))).willReturn(true);`. But i still dont understand why this is not working `given(service.method(someObjectDTO)).willReturn(true);` :-(